# Conditional data selection with text string data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've looked but seem to be coming up dry for an answer to the following question.

I have a pandas dataframe analogous to this (call it 'df'):

```
        Type              Set
    1   theGreen          Z
    2   andGreen          Z           
    3   yellowRed         X
    4   roadRed           Y
```

I want to add another column to the dataframe (or generate a series) of the same length as the dataframe (= equal number of records/rows) which assigns a numerical coding variable (1) if the Type contains the string "Green", (0) otherwise.

Essentially, I'm trying to find a way of doing this:

```
   df['color'] = np.where(df['Type'] == 'Green', 1, 0)
```

Except instead of the usual numpy operators (<,>,==,!=, etc.) I need a way of saying "in" or "contains". Is this possible? Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['color'] = np.where(df['Type'].str.contains('Green'), 1, 0)
print (df)
        Type Set  color
1   theGreen   Z      1
2   andGreen   Z      1
3  yellowRed   X      0
4    roadRed   Y      0
```

Another solution with `apply`:

```
df['color'] = np.where(df['Type'].apply(lambda x: 'Green' in x), 1, 0)
print (df)
        Type Set  color
1   theGreen   Z      1
2   andGreen   Z      1
3  yellowRed   X      0
4    roadRed   Y      0
```

Second solution is faster, but doesn't work with `NaN` in column `Type`, then return `error`:

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

**Timings**:

```
#[400000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)  

In [276]: %timeit df['color'] = np.where(df['Type'].apply(lambda x: 'Green' in x), 1, 0)
10 loops, best of 3: 94.1 ms per loop

In [277]: %timeit df['color1'] = np.where(df['Type'].str.contains('Green'), 1, 0)
1 loop, best of 3: 256 ms per loop
```

Comment: Could you write a function that handles ```NaN``` and apply it instead of the lambda?

Comment: @wwii I am only on phone. I add solution tomorrow.

Comment: @wwii - it is more complicated - for me works `df['color'] = np.where(df['Type'].apply(lambda x: 'Green' in x if pd.notnull(x) else False), 1,
              np.where(df['Type'].isnull(), np.nan, 0))` with `df = pd.DataFrame({
'Set': {1: 'Z', 2: 'Z', 3: 'X', 4: 'Y'}, 
'Type': {1: 'theGreen', 2: 'andGreen', 3: 'yellowRed', 4: np.nan}}, columns= ['Type','Set'])`

Comment: I was thinking more like - ```def is_green(thing): try: return 'Green' in thing;  except (ValueError, TypeError) as e: return False``` - then, ```df['color'] = np.where(df['Type'].apply(is_green), 1, 0)```